# How do I make the changes from table cell editing permanent?

Tags: java, javafx, javabeans

I'm trying to save the changes to the table when I run the application again. The code below allows the user to edit the cells and it commits the changes, but when I run the application again, the changes are not saved. How do I make the changes from table cell editing permanent? The code is below. (which is from oracle's website). I tried playing around with it but with no success.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewSample extends Application {

    private final TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
            new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
            new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
            new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com"));
    final HBox hb = new HBox();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        stage.setWidth(450);
        stage.setHeight(550);

        final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

        table.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = 
            new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));

        firstNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Person>forTableColumn());
        firstNameCol.setOnEditCommit(
            (CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) -> {
                ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setFirstName(t.getNewValue());
        });


        TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = 
            new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));
       lastNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Person>forTableColumn());
       lastNameCol.setOnEditCommit(
            (CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) -> {
                ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setLastName(t.getNewValue());
        });

        TableColumn<Person, String> emailCol = new TableColumn<>("Email");
        emailCol.setMinWidth(200);
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<>("email"));
        emailCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Person>forTableColumn());       
        emailCol.setOnEditCommit(
            (CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) -> {
                ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setEmail(t.getNewValue());
        });

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);

        final TextField addFirstName = new TextField();
        addFirstName.setPromptText("First Name");
        addFirstName.setMaxWidth(firstNameCol.getPrefWidth());
        final TextField addLastName = new TextField();
        addLastName.setMaxWidth(lastNameCol.getPrefWidth());
        addLastName.setPromptText("Last Name");
        final TextField addEmail = new TextField();
        addEmail.setMaxWidth(emailCol.getPrefWidth());
        addEmail.setPromptText("Email");

        final Button addButton = new Button("Add");
        addButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
            data.add(new Person(
                    addFirstName.getText(),
                    addLastName.getText(),
                    addEmail.getText()));
            addFirstName.clear();
            addLastName.clear();
            addEmail.clear();
        });

        hb.getChildren().addAll(addFirstName, addLastName, addEmail, addButton);
        hb.setSpacing(3);

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table, hb);

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Person {

        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty email;

        private Person(String fName, String lName, String email) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
            this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName) {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName) {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email.get();
        }

        public void setEmail(String fName) {
            email.set(fName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: None of your code is storing anything permanently. If you want that, you need to program it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a persistence layer, for example a database to store the values and to retrieve them later, Or simply you use a text file where you write the enetered values each separated by a separator of your choice.

Comment: I'm using a database actually, (in my code) the values are from a a database. But I don't know how to get the value from the textfield in a variable then save it. (I know how to save it in the database), but just the method for getting the value from the textfield

Comment: but you said that you want to have these values even if you re-run the program, how could that be valid if they did not come from a database ?

Comment: yeah i do.. i'm confused about your question. They do come from a database(in my code that is).

Comment: @user8783104: change your question to reflect what you ask: "getting the value from the textfield"

Answer (score 0):

From the comments I understand that the question is how to get the data from the table, so you can write it to a database.
The table information is represented by `ObservableList<Person> data`. It always reflects the actual table information.
To get the information simply loop over it. Run the following test :

Add a method to print some of the table's data:

```
private void printSomeTableData() {

    for(Person p : data) {

        System.out.println(p.getFirstName() + ", " + p.lastName.get()+ ", " +p.getEmail());
    }
}
```

In the constructor add a button to use this method:

```
final Button printButton = new Button("Print");
printButton.setOnAction(e -> printSomeTableData());
//change 
// hb.getChildren().addAll(addFirstName, addLastName, addEmail, addButton);
//to
hb.getChildren().addAll(addFirstName, addLastName, addEmail, addButton, printButton);
```

Whenever you press "print" **updated** table data prints out. 
I hope this simple test makes the mechanism clear. 
Think of `TableView` as a graphic representation of `ObservableList<Person> data`. Any change in the table information is reflected in `data`.

Comment: his thx it does get the value BUT it remains null because it returns the old value not the value the user inputted in the textfield. which might mean inputting the value in the text field does not update the list.

Comment: I don't know do you mean by "it". Looking at the comments I figured out that it is clear: You need to get the updated data, make it persistent (database) and reload data from the database  when you launch the application.

Comment: it is the printed value. I'm saying that the code you provided doesn't get the updated data, it gets the data before the user edits the cells. hence, prints null

Comment: If you print it after the table is populated (actually after 'data' was initialized) it will not print null. It always reflects the actual table information.

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't mean null but the old values, I tried in so many places but it doesn't work, it seems to only work within the setOnEditCommit function (because that's when the event is triggered), but i can't get the values out of there. i'll try your edited answer now.

Answer (score 0):

From comments I've seen that you didn't know how to get the values from textfields... Well, this is very simple, try something like this: textFieldName.getText() and you will have the value of that TextField :)

**EDIT:**
For iterating over a TableView do something like this:

```
   for (Person person : table.getItems()){ writeToDatabase(person.getFirstName());}
```

Comment: The data that is needed for persistence is stored in the table model (`data`)

Comment: So, you want to get the data from table?

Comment: Yes, to write it to a database.